# Group ring is not isomorphic to 2 by 2 matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let k be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. How to prove that $M_2$(k), the
k-algebra of 2 by  2 matrices over k, is not isomorphic to the group ring of any finite group G
over k.

Answer (score 3):

Any such group must have order 4 and any group of order 4 is abelian so its group ring must be commutative. However, $M_2(k)$ is not commutative.

Answer (score 3):

The group ring of a finite group is simple iff the group is trivial.

Indeed, there is always a $k$-algebra morphism $kG\to k$, coming from the trivial representation which, if $kG$ is simple, must be injective: this is only possible if $\dim kG=1$, that is, if $G$ is trivial.

Now matrix algebras are simple, so you get what you want.

Comment: This shows that no group algebra is isomorphic to no matrix algebra of any size —except in the trivial case.